# Is it possible to fix this css without position:relative?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a comment box which works but I am just having some minor issues, I am trying to create it like this

http://puu.sh/cBbFh/16a66b64d3.png

Which I know how to do but completely ruins the view of it in different screen sizes.

MY CSS:

```
.search69 {
padding: 40px;
background: #232323;
}
```

MY CODE (USING PHP AND HTML)

```
        <div class="search69">


        <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])  
    && !empty($_POST['name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['comment']) ){

$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];


$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=service.php'>";
}
else
{
echo "";
}
?>





        <form class="comments" action="service.php" method="POST">

<table>

<tr><td><h2>Name: </h2><br><input type="text" name="name" required/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><h2>Comment:</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="32" required></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"></td></tr>

</table>
</form>



<?php


$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
$id=$rows['id'];
$name=$rows['name'];
$comment=$rows['comment'];
echo '<h2><hr size="1"/>Posted By..<br>' . $name . '<h2><br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
;}



?>



</div>
```

Any idea's? Thanks!

Comment: It would be more useful if you posted the generated html instead of the php/html mash up.

Comment: @Musa What were you referring to? All my code?

Answer (score 2):

---

#### Aside - You need to update your PHP

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

---

Put the `<table>` down, Sarah, and we'll forget this ever happened.

- The table is removed along with its `<td>` and `<tr>` elements
- The form is wrapped in a div
- The div wrapper is given a sane `max-width`
- The form elements are positioned with `display: block` to move them to their own lines
- The labels are wrapped in `<label>` with the `for` attribute matching it's input / textareas `id` attribute.
- The submit comment is changed to the `<button>` element. The button works the same way, but is more flexible when it comes to CSS styling
- The `<hr>`'s are replaced with borders

### Working Example

```css
.formContainer {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #232323;
  color: #FFF;
  max-width: 500px;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 span {
  display: block;
}
input,
textarea,
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
textarea {
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
}
form {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #FFF;
}
form button {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.formContainer p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.formContainer p:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #FFF;
  margin: 0;
}
label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="formContainer">
  <form class="comments" action="service.php" method="POST">

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required/>
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment">Comment</button>


  </form>

  <h2>Posted By<span>Matt</span></h2>
  <p>I love puppies!</p>


</div>
```

#### Copy Paste

```
<div class="formContainer">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  
    && !empty($_POST['name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['comment']))
{

$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];

    // !! This needs to be replaced with PDO / mysqli !!
    // !! At the moment this is wide open for SQL injection !!
    $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");
    echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=service.php'>";
}

?>





<form class="comments" action="service.php" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required/>
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment">Comment</button>
</form>



<?php


$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
    $id=$rows['id'];
    $name=$rows['name'];
    $comment=$rows['comment'];
    echo '<h2>Posted By<span>' . $name . '</span></h2> <p>' . $comment . '</p>';
}



?>



</div>
```

Comment: Have you stripped out `<table>` / `<tr>` / `<td>` / `<hr>` ?

Comment: Yes, I have I am unsure of what to do next :(

Comment: OK, can you send a link to the live site?

Comment: Just copy HIS code and re-input your custom code.  His works wonderfully.

Comment: @misterManSam I haven't uplodaded it, it's just on my localhost. Is it possible for you to alter my code using snippet and insert the correct code? I've tried and I keep getting the same style. :(

Comment: @Sarah - I have added a copy paste snippet at the bottom of my answer. You will need to also remove any CSS that deals with form elements so there is no conflict. Also, you need to update your PHP and use the PDO or mysqli extension / sanitize your inputs [Read more over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/2930477)

Comment: @misterManSam Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd6\pages\service.php on line 157

Comment: @Sarah - There was an erroneous `.` Close the paragraph on this line - `echo '<h2>Posted By<span>' . $name . '</span></h2> <p>' . $comment . '</p>';`

Comment: It's impossible to tell what is going on without seeing the live page. All I can say is to remove all your CSS and HTML and replace it with the copy paste in my answer and my CSS.